# Unable to store Enum in batch way with spring-jdbc NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm facing a enum problem with spring-jdbc. I have a POJO wich contains an enum value. I want to store the string value in database, not the ordinal. I made a DAO and it's work well except for batch methods with a namedParameterJdbcTemplate (for jdbcTemplate and BatchPreparedStatementSetter it works but i prefer to use named parameters).

For instance:

```
public int[] batchUpdate(List<MyPojo> pojos) throws DaoException {
    SqlParameterSource[] parameters = new SqlParameterSource[pojos.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < pojos.size(); i++) {
        parameters[i] = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(pojos.get(i));
    }

    try {
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL_UPDATE, (SqlParameterSource[]) parameters);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DaoException(ex);
    }
}
```

doesn't work for enums properties.

I have this error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column
>   "STATUS CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL":
>   "'aced00057e7200466f72672e67656e792e7064702e6669726562697264732e67656e79746f74652e646f6d61696e6d6f64656c2e6265742e4265744465636f6...
>   (258)"; SQL statement: UPDATE ... SET ..., status = ? WHERE id = ? [22001-187]    at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:327)    at
>   org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:737)  at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:125)     at
>   org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)  at
>   org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:157)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1005)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:989)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
>     ... 43 more

MyPojo has an enum value (status). It's strange because the enum string I want to store is 'validated' not 'aced000...'. If I was using JPA, I would used `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` for my status field but does a stuff like this exists on spring-jdbc ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved by registering sql type:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < bets.size(); i++) {
        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource bpsps = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(pojos.get(i));
        bpsps.registerSqlType("status", Types.VARCHAR);
        parameters[i] = bpsps;
    }
```